# How to create WritebleBitmap from a resource image with C++ for Windows Metro app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx, imaging

I can easily create a BitmapImage from a resource JPG image file using the following code...

```
Windows::Foundation::Uri^ uri = ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri(L"ms-appx:///Hippo.JPG");
Imaging::BitmapImage^ image = ref new Imaging::BitmapImage(uri);
```

But WritableBitmap does not take an Uri. I see a SetSource method, but that needs a IRandomaccessStream and not an Uri. And I have no clue how to create one from a JPG file. I searched the net over and over again, but could not find a straight forward answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want something like this...

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::WriteableBitmap image = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::WriteableBitmap();
image->SetSource(somehowGetRandomAccessStreamFromUri);
```

But, how do I get the IRandomaccessStream instance from a uri? I started working on C++ Metro app only today, so might be wrong, but I find it to be overly complicated with too much of onion peeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you would do something like

```
var storageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(relativePath.Replace('/', '\\'));
var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
wb.SetSource(stream);
```

I think in C++/CX you would do something like this:

```
#include <ppl.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>

...

Concurrency::task<Windows::Storage::StorageFile^> getFileTask
    (Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync(L"Assets\\MyImage.jpg"));

auto getStreamTask = getFileTask.then(
    [] (Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^storageFile)
    {
        return storageFile->OpenReadAsync();
    });

getStreamTask.then(
    [] (Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^ stream)
    {
        auto wb = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
        wb->SetSource(stream);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Filip, it worked like a charm. I had to do one small change though. Changed L"Assets\\MyImage.jpg" to L"MyImage.jpg" as I was getting an invalid argument exception for some reason.

Comment: Finally figured out that WritableBitmap's pixel content is neither readable nor writable :( I can get an IBuffer pointer which does not provide the access to it's buffer! Anyway that is a separate matter all together.

Comment: @abix In C# I used the [AsStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.windowsruntimebufferextensions.asstream(v=vs.110).aspx#Y0) method to convert the buffer to an I/O stream. It must be doable in C++ too. Check C# samples [here](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit).

Comment: I found a solution in another forum as in how to get the byte* from IBuffer...

 IUnknown* pUnk = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(writableImage->PixelBuffer);
 IBufferByteAccess* pBufferByteAccess = nullptr;
 HRESULT hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBufferByteAccess));
 byte *pixels = nullptr;
 pBufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels);